# Calculating probability from multivariate logistic regression using odds instead of log odds

Tags: r, probability, odds

Question: is there a way to calculate probability from odds ratios instead of log odds ratios?

I am trying to wrap my head around calculating probability from a multivariate logistic regression model I have derived in R.

In my article, I explore the risk for complication with surgery given a set of variables. After deriving the multivariate logistic regression model using the glm function in R, I have for each row (patient) in my dataset used the predict function to calculate the predicted risk for each patient. I do this in order to compare my prediction model to the actual risk for complication.

I understand that the predict function uses the formula

$$
Probability = \frac{e^{intercept+ln(OR_{sum})}}{1+e^{intercept + ln(OR_{sum})}}
$$

where ORsum = sum of log odds ratios

In order for my data to make sense in a clinical setting, I will be plotting this function with ORsum on the x-axis and probability on the y-axis. This is a rather common approach.

By plotting the function, the reader can determine the risk of a patient by looking up the ORsum on the x-axis.

[image]

However, medical articles often present odds ratios and very rarely **log** odds ratios as these are even more complicated to make sense in a clinical setting.

Question: is there a way to calculate probability from odds ratios? I believe I must use the **product** of odds ratios (instead of sum), but I can't wrap my head around how to convert the formula to odds ratios from log odds ratios.